services.app.build contains unsupported option: 'ssh'
I am trying to create a docker-compose file that uses a previously made docker file that I build with this command:
docker build --ssh default=~/.ssh/id_rsa .

However I am having trouble replicating this in a docker-compose yml file:
version: '3.8'

services:
    app:
        image: python:3.11
        build:
            context: .
            ssh:
                - default=~/.ssh/id_rsa
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ...


I keep getting the same error:
ERROR: The Compose file './compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app.build contains unsupported option: 'ssh'

which is very confusing for me because according to the documentation this should be fine.
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown

Please help I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

You're using compose version 1 and the docs are for version 2.  You should upgrade.

Oh that explains everything. Thank you

Compose file format version 3 doesn't support a build: { ssh: } option.
This is relevant because you're using the old Python-based version of Docker Compose.  This supports file formats versions 1, 2, and 3, but it does not support any extensions in the "specification" file format.
For build: { ssh: } to work, you need to update to the newer plugin-based version of Compose.  It would be good practice to update the version: line to indicate you're using "specification"-only features (I tend to write version: "4.x"), but the plugin version of Compose ignores the version: line (and gives an incorrect warning if it's present).
It's also possible your system has both versions installed, in which case docker compose build (with a space between docker and compose, not a hyphen) might work.
